# Disable Bluetooth permanently

Tags: bluetooth

How do you permanently disable Bluetooth on OS X Mavericks?  It seems that simply shutting it off in preferences doesn't disable it.

Comment: What makes you say that the bluetooth isn't disable ?

Comment: can you explain why you think it is still on? are you talking about cutting the wires ?

Comment: I actually did physically remove the bluetooth radio from my MacBook Pro and it was still able to discover and connect to bluetooth devices!

Comment: That is not possible, but I hope you are not one of those surgeons cutting out the wrong organ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [gist](https://gist.github.com/midore/3870046) that removes the launchds & the kernel extensions for the bluetooth. It will make the system incapable of using the bluetooth features  :

```
#!/bin/bash

# disable bluetooth
# OS X 10.8.2
# 2012-10-08

home=$HOME
bk=$home/backup-bluetooth-extentions
mkdir $bk

# sudo reboot with Shift Key # Safty Boot
# Login as Admin usert.

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Local Backup OFF
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# sudo tmutil disable
# sudo tmutil disablelocal

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Agnet
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# bluetooth
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.bluetoothUIServer.plist
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.bluetoothAudioAgent.plist

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Daemon
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.bnepd.plist
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.IOBluetoothUSBDFU.plist

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Extentions
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Driver
sudo mv /System/Library/Extensions/AppleBluetoothMultitouch.kext $bk
sudo mv /System/Library/Extensions/IOBluetoothFamily.kext $bk
sudo mv /System/Library/Extensions/IOBluetoothHIDDriver.kext $bk

# Bluetooth Mouns & Keyboard
sudo mv /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHIDKeyboard.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard.kext $bk
sudo mv /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHIDMouse.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleBluetoothHIDMouse.kext $bk

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# touch
sudo touch /System/Library/Extensions

echo 'Shut Down & Restart'
```